# Lightweight library for canvas zoom and pan?

Tags: javascript, html

I recently decided to use google maps with overlays to display some custom maps in the entire body of my web-page but I'm afraid google maps is a bit too much than what I need. I basically just need to place objects on a canvas, then zoom and pan that canvas. I tried patching something together myself but realized that things became complicated quite fast. So I'm wondering if there is some sort of library to help me out with my problem?

I have heard of kinetic.js but it seems to be a bit outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [jquery.panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom)

I've personally used the angular variant of this, but it was using the source as this.

Comment: if you're using angular , then this works fine too  https://github.com/mvindahl/angular-pan-zoom